# Docker Entrypoint environment variables not printed

Tags: docker

I'm new to Docker. All I want is to print an environment variable I pass to docker run via the `-e` flag. My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ENTRYPOINT echo $TEST
```

I build my image with `docker build -t test-docker .` and execute it with `docker run test-docker -e TEST=bar`. It just prints an empty line and exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you run the image having parameters in wrong order, should be:

```
docker run --rm -e TEST=bar test-docker
```

Notice the env var is specified before the image name. Everything after your image name is considered as an argument of your container.

Use `--rm` always when playing to prevent garbage containers from piling up.